# Prove $\lim_{z\to 2i}(2x+iy^2)=4i $ using definition

Tags: complex-numbers

Help me with this exercise:

Proof using definition,

$$\lim_{z\to 2i}(2x+iy^2)=4i $$

if given $\epsilon >0$ I can find $\delta>0 $ such that,.

If $0<|z-2i|<\delta$ then $|2x+iy^2-4i|<\epsilon $

---

Comment: So far so good. How do you propose to find $\delta$, after being given $\epsilon$?

Comment: what are x and y?

Comment: @MyGlasses When $z\to i2$, $y\to 2$.  ;-))

Answer (score 0):

First, we restrict $z-2i$ so that $|z-2i|\le 1$.  Then, $1\le y\le 3$ and $y+2\le 5$.  Hence, we can write

$$\begin{align}
|2x+iy^2-4i|&=|2(x-0)+i(y^2-4)|\\\\
&\le \sqrt{4(x-0)^2+(y+2)^2(y-2)^2}\\\\
&\le\sqrt{4x^2+25(y-2)^2}\\\\
&\le 5\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-2)^2}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|z-i2|=\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-2)^2}<\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{5}\right)$.  And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to given you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Answer (score -1):

If you take $z=x+yi$ 
$$\lim_{z\to 2i}(2x+iy^2)=4i\\\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,2)}(2x+iy^2)=4i\\
0<|\sqrt{(x-o)^2+(y-2)^2}|<\delta \Rightarrow |2x+iy^2-4i|<\epsilon\\
0<|\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}|<\delta \Rightarrow |2x+i(y^2-4)|<\epsilon\\ 
0<|\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}|<\delta \Rightarrow \sqrt{(2x)^2+(y^2-4)^2}<\epsilon\\\to \\\sqrt{(2x)^2+(y^2-4)^2}=\sqrt{4x^2+(y+2)^2(y-2)^2}<2\sqrt{4x^2+16(y-2)^2}=\\2.2\sqrt{x^2+4(y-2)^2}<4\sqrt{4x^2+4(y-2)^2}=8\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}<\epsilon\\$$so 
$$\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}<\dfrac {\epsilon} {8}$$and you can take $\delta <\dfrac {\epsilon} {8}$

Comment: $2.2$ means $2\times2$.?

Comment: Yes I usually use "." for the meaning of $\times$

Comment: How is $y+2$ less than $4$?  $y$ is not less than $2$.